# Name That ...Name? 16

Tags: knowledge

My sediments had a political run

I had pieces of piece with a lot of fun

A Greek myth has me teaching a lady

Though my methods are misogynistic and shady

Name the name

Answer (score 1):

Okay, worth a shot, although I'm pretty sure I'm wrong.

> Peneus

My sediments had a political run

> The Pineios river, named for this Greek god, has a significant delta that is protected by a number of international treaties.

I had pieces of piece with a lot of fun

> No idea on this line. Not even sure what "pieces of piece" could mean.

A Greek myth has me teaching a lady

> Daphne was the daughter of Peneus. He would have taught her as she was growing up.

Though my methods are misogynistic and shady

> Peneus turned Daphne into a tree (thus "shady") to save her from the pursuits of Apollo.

Answer (score 0):

It could be

> Spiderman

As,

My sediments had a political run

> Not sure

I had pieces of piece with a lot of fun

> It could be the weaving thread, which can be in pieces out of a single one.

A Greek myth has me teaching a lady

> *Minerva* teaching *Arachne*... and Arachne refers to spider.

Though my methods are misogynistic and shady

> Usually, Spiderman deeds are male-oriented and not *so bright*...( not fully sure).

Name the name

> Spiderman.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doesn't fit perfectly but here's my try:

> Mars

Line 1:

> Exploring the dry riverbeds or 'sediments' of Mars has been a political issue for many countries.

Line 2:

> Mars/Ares, as the god of war, probably had a lot of fun (according to his own definition of fun)

Line 3:

> The Amazons are children of Ares, so maybe this line refers to their mutual love of fighting?

Line 4:

> War is mostly seen as a masculine activity, and shady stuff happens during wars.